# Python pandas - extract and replace

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame column containing elements similar to the string `McNally, King  (XYZ)`. I would like to keep the last name, first name and remove everything else. Therefore after cleaning `McNally, King  (XYZ)` should be `McNally, King`.

I have tried following two functions but not getting the desired result:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.extract(r'\w+\,\s[A-Z][a-z]+', expand=False)

df['name'] = df['name'].replace({r'\w+\,\s[A-Z][a-z]+' : r'\w+\,\s[A-Z][a-z]+'}, regex=True)
```

Second code replaces the substring with the regex itself, while the first code extracts the names from the string but I want to keep the name and remove everything else followed by the name.

Edit:
Sample data:

```
Reyes, Rebecca  L (XYZ)
Derry, Odd     P (XYZ)
Garza, Per-Laura   A (MNP)
Fernandez, Rafael   Carl (XYZ)
```

Expected output:

```
Reyes, Rebecca
Derry, Odd
Garza, Per-Laura
Fernandez, Rafael
```

I would like to edit-in-place i.e. modify the existing datafame itself and not creating a new one.

Comment: Where's your data?

Comment: Data is in a CSV file which I am reading using pandas.read_csv as dataframe then doing the cleanup.

Comment: So where is it? We want to see it, along with your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['McNally, King  (XYZ)']}, index=[0])
df['name'].str.extract(r'(\w+,\s\w+)')
```

Output:

```
0    McNally, King
Name: name, dtype: object
```